# How to run exsicting ionic app

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic app with this folder structure

[image]

How can I run this app, knowing that I have node and ionic npm  installed in my PC

Comment: What's inside `src` folder?

Answer (score 0):

Type `ionic serve` to run your app on the browser

Comment: Here is the error message when doing ionic serve  "www" directory cannot be found. Please make sure the working directory is an Ionic project.
There was an error serving your Ionic application: "www" directory cannot be found. Please make sure the working directory is an Ionic project.

Comment: I think your src folder is the www directory, refer [Link](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/206)

Answer (score 0):

Follow steps below:

Open command prompt in windows and goto your app folder using cd command in cmd.
Once you're in, just write ionic serve to see app running in browser.

To run it in device, first build it using `ionic platform add android` Then `ionic build` Next `ionic run android`
It will run application in connected device or emulator.
Make aure you have android setup in your system for this.

Comment: I have a message error after doing that                                                                                "www" directory cannot be found. Please make sure the working directory is an Ionic project.
There was an error serving your Ionic application: "www" directory cannot be found. Please make sure the working directory is an Ionic project.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have www folder. It's a folder where your html and js and css files are. Without it you don't have an app.

I recommend creating entirely new ionic project with `ionic start ProjectName`

Then you will be able to run it with `ionic serve` and see the structure so you can figure out how to run your example

Answer (score 0):

In you have this inside your `src` folder

- css
- img
- js
- lib
- index.html

just rename `src` to `www` and then run `ionic serve`.

[image]